# How to get events in real-time using ETW (StartTrace etc.)?

Tags: c, winapi, real-time, etw

In Event Tracing for Windows, `StartTrace` accepts an [`EVENT_TRACE_PROPERTIES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363784.aspx) structure that allows for a `FlushTimer` which specifies how frequently unfull buffers should be flushed.

The thing is, `FlushTimer` is a `ULONG` representing *seconds*, but I want it to be very small so that it's nearly instantaneous (on the order of milliseconds).

I don't know how Process Monitor manages to get ETW events in real-time, but it does, so surely there must be a way to do it.

So the question is: How can I receive real-time events, you know, in real time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ETW does not support real time notifications. Even the so-called `EVENT_TRACE_REAL_TIME_MODE` isn't really real-time as the documentation clearly says.

The premise of your question is wrong: Sysinternals Process Monitor **does not** use ETW to get its synchronous kind-of real-time process, thread, module, file and Registry events. You've got two options:

1. Use ETW - which is not what ProcMon does - and get events they way ETW provides them to you.
2. Do what ProcMon does - which is not consume ETW events - and get events synchronously, like ProcMon gets them.